# How to send USB requests from windows application to a USB device

Tags: directshow, winusb

Currently I am working in amcap windows streaming application. For that I have downloaded the source from GitHub[https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples.git].Now from that application I need to send USB requests like bmRequestType,bRequest,wValue,wIndex,wLength to my USB device.I have tried using WinUsb API's but WinUsb_Initialize() returns false.Can I use WinUsb APIs there any other APIs or any .net frameworks in sending the USB requests from windows host system.

To get the device handle I have used RetrieveDevicePath() from the official Microsoft documentations.